# Is there a way to handle an exception thrown from inside of custom exception handler in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

Let's say a Spring Boot (2.1) has a `@RestControllerAdvice` which handles some custom exception.

What if during an exception handler call, another exception is thrown. Is there a way to handle it rather than having Spring to send its own response body, which might look something like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-31T03:03:55.228+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "account: 2",
    "path": "/myendpoint/2"
}

@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  private MyOtherService otherService;

  @ExceptionHandler(SomeCustomException.class)
  public ResponseBody<Object> handleCustomException(SomeCustomException ex) {
    otherService.doSomething(); // This might throw, say, a RuntimeException

    return new ResponseBody<>(/* ... */);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to have a custom exception class and throw that custom exception for any exception occurred in anywhere in the code. And after doing that you can have a exception handler for that custom exception.

Comment: @animeshk An exception is thrown from the exception handler. How does what you are saying help?

Comment: From my experience one should not throw exception from exception handler/controller advice, same is true if you checkout spring default controller advice. One should return HTTP response code either 404/500 or any other as per the type of custom exception error code.

Comment: @animeshk I do not dispute your approach, and I do share your goal. Unfortunately, in my situation, an exception is being thrown by a Spring interceptor associated with my handler which has been designed by another team. Even if I catch that specific exception, I have to return different response based on the URI, which I won't have access to when implement `@ExceptionHandler` (say, for a `RuntimeException`). I'm trying to see if I can ask them to change their behavior on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExceptionHandler is a [fault barrier](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/enterprise-architecture/effective-exceptions-part2.html), so you need to handle the exception without throwing another one.